# How to statistically best compare two lists of Pearson correlations for significance?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance

I have two sets or lists of data that only include Pearson correlation results. The values include positive and negative Pearson correlations, say list 1 and list 2, such as follows:

```
list_1 = [0.32, 0.15, 0.6, ...]
list_2 = [0.53, 0.02, -0.43, ...]
```

The number of values in both lists is always the same. The number of values ranges from approximately 3000 to 100.000 values, depending on the samples. Moreover, these are paired or repeated measures samples, hence both lists of data stem from the same subjects, but obtained in different research conditions.

**Aim:** My aim is to test if there is a statistically significant difference between both lists. In some cases the data in both lists is normally distributed, in others it is not.

**Question:** Would the following steps to test for a statistical significant difference between both lists be appropriate?

1. Convert the single Pearson correlations of both lists to Fisher Z values, i.e., Fisher r-to-Z transform for all values;
2. Apply a paired t-Test between both lists or a Wilcoxon-signed rank test in case the data lacks the parametic test assumptions to test if the distributions between list 1 and 2 significantly diverge.

I am not sure if that approach is correct, since both lists of data include correlation results. For example, would it be better to compute the median Pearson correlation (or median Fisher Z value) for each list to subsequently perform another test between both resulting correlation or Fisher Z values that take the number of observations into consideration? An example of that would be *point 8* as shown in this link: https://www.psychometrica.de/correlation.html

I wonder if my simple approach above is fine or if it has serious flaws.

Comment: When you say that your `aim is to test if there is a statistically significant difference between both lists`, difference in what? Mean, median, distribution, something else?

Comment: Well... that complicates things, have a read at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_test or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that out. In case the power of that test is low, it would also be interesting to check if the distribution between both lists is significantly different, so that is still an option too.

Comment: How about the 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov–Smirnov_test